# JCTI Test: Find the next box

Tags: pattern, matches

[image: Find the next pattern]

This is a JCTI question ,where I need to fill up the blank spot by any of the 6 given boxes.
[image]

I cannot understand from where these two balls within a single box is coming. All the previous boxes contained just one ball! Moreover the first two (up and down in a single column) are squares, the second two are rhombuses, the third two are again squares, so the last two (the rightmost one and the one to be filled up) should be rhombuses. But given is a square!! Please solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two balls in the single box comes from the two different tracks moving together. The puzzle is designed to suggest that there are two different tracks that collide, which implies that what you're looking at in the missing box is the combination of the two.

There's the hint. Here's the answer:

> **Option 1.** The tracks show you what happens when the balls move from a square into a rotated square and back. In the first track, the ball moves clockwise in both steps. In the second track, the ball moves clockwise into a diamond, and counterclockwise twice back into the square.
>
>  Consequently, the top track moves into the right side, and the bottom track moves into the left side. In the step after this, they overlap.

Comment: Darn, same answer in progress :P

Comment: @Danikov Hehe, I am a master ninja! Also, welcome to Puzzling :]

Answer (score 0):

option 1; the square on top has a clearly defined pattern of rotating rightwards on a 35 degree, the square on the bottom initially rotates in the same angle and direction as the square previously mentioned but then takes an "unexpected" leftward turn,and then it proceeds to turn again rightwards as it did initially.